# Что за инструкция с оператором => в коде?

Tags: c#, lambda

```
// настройка полей с помощью Fluent API
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
    .Property(c => c.FirstName).IsRequired().HasMaxLength(30);

modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
    .Property(c => c.Email).HasMaxLength(100);

modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
    .Property(c => c.Photo).HasColumnType("image");
```

Что это вот за инструкции в коде выше?

```
c => c.FirstName
c => c.Email
c => c.Photo
```

Comment: ламбды https://msdn.microsoft.com/uk-ua/library/bb397687%28v=vs.110%29.aspx и деревья выражений https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654263.aspx

Comment: там белым по черному написано [Fluent API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591617(v=vs.113).aspx)

Comment: А не, не о том вопрос.

Comment: @Grundy, что-то ты с простого вопроса отправляешь в более сложный. Не надо так дубликатить :) Да и вообще, там же не то.

Comment: @Qwertiy, он там оказался вообще о другом :-) просто увидел лямбда в заголовке и вопрос что такое стрелочка, жмакнул, а потом только вчитался

Comment: @Grundy, ну так отмени?

Comment: @Qwertiy, Но тогда я больше не смогу проголосовать за закрытие :-) а это 100% дубликат! надо только вопрос подходящий найти :)

Comment: Голосую за переоткрытие т.к. проставлен некорректный дубликат.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Конструкции вида `x => x.Email` (а также более сложные, вида `(x, y) => x.Email + y.Age` или там `n => { int s = 0; while (n-- > 0) s += n * n; return s; }`) — это *лямбда-выражения*. Они используются в C# в двух смыслах.

Если в этом месте *ожидается* делегат/метод/что-то такое, то лямбда имеет смысл локально-определённой функции. Например, такой код:

```
Func<Entity, string> f = (c => c.FirstName);
```

по существу не отличается от кода

```
Func<Entity, string> f = GetFirstName;
```

```
static string GetFirstName(Entity c)
{
    return c.FirstName;
}
```

(но записывается быстрее). Кроме того (и это очень важно и удобно), лямбды могут ссылаться на локальные переменные и поля, видимые в точке определения. Например, так:

```
int x = hey.GimmeSomeX();
Func<int, int> f = n => n * x;
```

Такого эффекта уже нельзя добиться с локальной функцией, поэтому компилятор «под капотом» использует более сложную конструкцию.

---

Если же в месте, где упоминается лямбда, ожидается специальная штука под названием [*дерево выражений*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt654263.aspx), то лямбда конвертируется в это самое дерево выражений. Имея дерево выражений, можно посмотреть программным путём, что же там внутри. В частности, если у вас есть `c.FirstName`, вы можете увидеть, что это обращение к полю с именем `FirstName`. Именно для этого оно используется в вашем примере.

Чем же дерево выражений лучше, чем просто передать строку `"FirstName"`? Дело в том, что в строке вы можете ошибиться, а вот за правильностью лямбда-выражения следит компилятор. Также при переименовании IDE сможет правильно подхватить изменения. А со строкой возможны, понятно, проблемы.

Answer (score 9):

Подобный код используется в C# для того, чтобы указать имя свойства без риска опечататься. В классическом коде это могло бы выглядеть так:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>()
            .Property("FirstName")
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(30);
```

Понятно, что при переименовании свойства `FirstName` код продолжает компилироваться, но перестаёт работать во время выполнения. Было бы неплохо использовать такую конструкцию, которая при переименовании свойства приводила бы к ошибке компиляции. Это давало бы нам возможность сразу обнаруживать и исправлять опечатки в названии полей.

Как раз для этого и применяют синтаксис, основанный на деревьях выражений:

```
public PrimitivePropertyConfiguration Property<T>(
Expression<Func<TStructuralType, T>> propertyExpression
)
where T : struct, new()
{
    . . .
}
```

Синтаксис страшноват, но он позволяет статически типизировать обращение к любому свойству класса. Что в данном случае происходит?

`Func<TStructuralType, T>` означает, что на вход ожидается лямбда-выражение, оно же *анонимная* (*безымянная*) функция. Синтаксис таких функций в C# выглядит как `x => Exp(x)`, где `x` — это параметр функции, а `Exp(x)` — какое-то не очень сложное выражение. В нашем случае это простое выражение — обращение к свойству объекта.

`Expression<Func<TStructuralType, T>>` означает, что мы не будем выполнять функцию непосредственно, а вместо этого построим дерево выражения и сохраним его в переменной типа [`Expression`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.linq.expressions.expression(v=vs.110).aspx).

Объект этого класса будет доступен во время выполнения и мы сможем пройтись по нему, и извлечь название свойства.

То, что это `Expression` именно от `Func<TStructuralType, T>` ограничивает способ задания параметра `propertyExpression`: мы ждём либо имя функции с одним параметром, либо анонимную функцию с одним параметром (она же лямбда).

Проще говоря, `Expression<Func<TStructuralType, T>>` означает, что при вызове `Property` в качестве параметра ожидается что-то вроде `x => Exp(x)`. Вы всё ещё можете *выстрелить себе в ногу* и написать неподходящее выражение, например, `x => x + x`, но так делать всё-таки не стоит.

Наконец, в чём главная магия, как устроен метод `Property`? В основе, конечно, лежит *рефлексия* и подробности можно посмотреть в [ответе на соответствующий вопрос на StackOverflow (англ.)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/672212/1051621).

Непосредственно в Entity Framework методы, извлекающие имя свойства из выражения, вынесены в класс [`ExpressionExtensions`](https://github.com/mono/entityframework/blob/70998a4be0ed566ad3f21d6c5a51016b7c16f9bd/src/EntityFramework/Utilities/ExpressionExtensions.cs).